# Angular 2 webpack loader for jsp

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, angular

I try to develop a maven project with Angular 2 with Spring security. 
The structure of the project is similar on this guide:
http://csetutorials.com/deploy-angular-2-maven-webapp-on-tomcat.html

But i am having a problem when building angular 2 using webpack. Because when i change a html to jsp in my angular 2. I get an error for (maven or npm) [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kThs0.png)

From that error, i try to find an appropriate loader to compile jsp file or some tweak for webpack to recognize .jsp file but i cant find any of those solutions. So is it webpack can't compile jsp files?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot of folks using webpack and JSP together.  This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837760/infinite-loop-between-jsp-and-webpack-angularjs-app) got no answers and ended up refactoring their code to solve the problem.  I would suggest to re-factor your JSPs away from your Angular2 (split it up), or replace the remaining JSPs with Angular2 code.

In [this page](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader/issues/45) the extract-text-webpack-plugin plugin is used with JSP, but I'm not at all certain it will achieve what you want.